# C program error negative inputs dont work

Tags: c

here is my code and im not sure what im doing wrong. it is a mean max and min calculator. the program works when it imputs positive values, but when the input value is negative, it messes up everything. I thought the problem was the data type so i tried to make it double but it still didnt work and i am out of ideas. maybe it has something with the if statements?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void)
{
   double min;
   double sum;
   double max;
   int i;
   int N;
   double Num;
   double avgMean;
   int flag=0;


   printf("MIN, Max, and Mean CALCULATOR\n\n\n");
   printf("How many values are to be entered? :\n");
   scanf("%d", &N);

   sum=0;

   for(i=1; i<=N; i++)
   {flag=0;
   while(1)
   {
      printf("Value %d:\n", i);
      flag=scanf("%lf", &Num);
      if (flag == 0)
      {
         printf("INPUT ERROR!\n");
      }
      else
      {
         break;
      }
   }


   if(i==1||Num>max)
   {
      max=Num;
   }

   if (i==1||Num<min)
   {
      min=Num;
   }

   sum=sum+Num;
}
printf("\n");
avgMean = sum / (float)N;

printf("The minimum value is %g, the maximum value is %g, and the average value is %g.\n", min, max, avgMean);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please include an example of the incorrect behavior (all inputs and outputs).

Comment: "but when the input value is negative, it messes up " --> Insure `N >= 1`, else code fails.  Without example , input, output and expected output, post is not sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

Program works fine with negative numbers on `gcc` compiler:

**FIRST RUN**

```
MIN, Max, and Mean CALCULATOR


How many values are to be entered? :
3
Value 1:
-2
Value 2:
-4
Value 3:
-5
The minimum value is -5, the maximum value is -2, and the average value is -3.66667.
```

**SECOND RUN**

```
MIN, Max, and Mean CALCULATOR


How many values are to be entered? :
6 
Value 1:
1
Value 2:
3
Value 3:
6
Value 4:
-8
Value 5:
-11
Value 6:
5

The minimum value is -11, the maximum value is 6, and the average value is -0.666667.
```

**THIRD RUN**

```
MIN, Max, and Mean CALCULATOR


How many values are to be entered? :
4
Value 1:
0
Value 2:
0
Value 3:
0
Value 4:
-3

The minimum value is -3, the maximum value is 0, and the average value is -0.75.
```

But to be on the safer side make this change:

```
if((flag == 0)||(num<0))
```